# Are newer apache commons libraries compatible with older ones

Tags: apache, version, backwards-compatibility, apache-commons-collection

Specifically, I am interested are new line 4.x **commons-collections** library backward compatible with 3.x version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the release notes for 4.0 version:

> To help with the migration to this new version, the package has changed to "org.apache.commons.collections4", thus it is possible to have both commons-collections versions in the classpath.

Source: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/release_4_0.html

This means that you can include both versions in your classpath without name collisions.